# Delegate with parameters... as a parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates

I have this method with its delegate that is used to append text to a multiline TextBox in the GUI from any of the threads in my WinForms application:

```
private delegate void TextAppendDelegate(TextBox txt, string text);
public void TextAppend(TextBox txt, string text)
{
  if(txt.InvokeRequired)
    txt.Invoke(new TextAppendDelegate(TextAppend), new object[] {txt, text });
  else
  {
    if(txt.Lines.Length == 1000)
    {
      txt.SelectionStart = 0;
      txt.SelectionLength = txt.Text.IndexOf("\n", 0) + 1;
      txt.SelectedText = "";
    }
    txt.AppendText(text + "\n");
    txt.ScrollToCaret();
  }
}
```

It works great, I just call TextAppend(myTextBox1, "Hi Worldo!") from any thread and the GUI is updated. Now, is there some way to pass a delegate that invokes TextAppend to one of my utility methods in another project without sending any reference to the actual TextBox, something that might look like this from the caller:

```
Utilities.myUtilityMethod(
    new delegate(string str){ TextAppend(myTextBox1, str) });
```

And in the callee, a definition similar to:

```
public static void myUtilityMethod(delegate del)
{
    if(del != null) { del("Hi Worldo!"); }
}
```

So that when this function is called, it invokes the TextAppend method with that string and the predefined TextBox the caller wants to use. Is this possible or am I crazy? I know there are way easier options like using interfaces or passing the TextBox and delegate, but I want to explore this solution because it seems more elegant and hides stuff from the callee. The problem is that I'm still too novice in C# and barely understand delegates, so please help me with the actual syntax that would work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of .NET/C#?

Comment: Can't you just move the entire TextAppend method into your utility class, then do Utility.TextAppend(MyTextbox, "foo") from the caller(s)?

Comment: A couple of questions to better understand your requirements. How are you expecting your `myUtilityMethod` to know that it has to pass a single string to your delegate? And how do you expect it to get the string to pass?

Comment: @Platinum Azure The version is 3.5

Comment: @Dylan Smith I would like to not move the method into the utility, because then I would need to pass a reference to my TextBox and also a delegate to my method TextAppend, so the utility can update the GUI. That's an easy solution yeah, but I would like to have something more shielded

Comment: @Enigmativity That's a good question and I have no idea. Maybe the parameter in the utility has to be like this: 
public static void myUtilityMethod(delegate(string) del)
?????
That is the stuff I don't know and I hope some of you kindly explain it

Comment: @RRuiz if you move TextAppend into the Utility class you don't need to pass a delegate because TextAppend would create it.  You just pass a reference to a textbox and the string you want to append.  sounds like a perfect use of a utility method to me (I would also probably make it an extension method on the TextBox class).

Comment: @Dylan Smith Thanks, I know that is a more direct solution (and probably more readable and maintainable) but I didn't want to move the method into the Utility class because it is already called from several points in the program and I had to make this minor change in all those places, adding the Utility class name before every call. Also, I'm obnoxious and don't like any method outside the Form class to get a reference to the GUI elements. In fact I didn't want to do this in the first place, but the necessity of printing stuff in the GUI from another class in another project just arised.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you're using C# 3 (VS2008) or later:

```
Utilities.myUtilityMethod(str => TextAppend(myTextBox1, str));

...

public static void myUtilityMethod(Action<string> textAppender)
{
    if (textAppender != null) { textAppender("Hi Worldo!"); }
}
```

If you're using .NET 2.0, you can use an anonymous method instead of a lambda expression:

```
Utilities.myUtilityMethod(delegate(string str) { TextAppend(myTextBox1, str); });
```

If you're using .NET 1.x, you need to define the delegate yourself and use a named method:

```
delegate void TextAppender(string str);

void AppendToTextBox1(string str)
{
    TextAppend(myTextBox1, str);
}

...

Utilities.myUtilityMethod(new TextAppender(AppendToTextBox1));

...

public static void myUtilityMethod(TextAppender textAppender)
{
    if (textAppender != null) { textAppender("Hi Worldo!"); }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I tested both the lambda expression and the anonymous method and they work flawlessly. Even the null condition works if I don't want to perform any action. Thank you very much!